# mix deps.get failed (seems missing ssl?)

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm sorry but I'm new to Elixir. while building phoenix application, `mix deps.get` failed with an error.

```
% mix deps.get
Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :phoenix
Shall I install Hex? [Yn] y
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:ssl, {'no such file or directory', 'ssl.app'}}}
    (mix) lib/mix/utils.ex:409: Mix.Utils.read_httpc/1
    (mix) lib/mix/utils.ex:354: Mix.Utils.read_path/2
    (mix) lib/mix/local.ex:107: Mix.Local.read_path!/2
    (mix) lib/mix/local.ex:86: Mix.Local.find_matching_versions_from_signed_csv!/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/local.hex.ex:23: Mix.Tasks.Local.Hex.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/loader.ex:140: Mix.Dep.Loader.with_scm_and_app/4
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/loader.ex:98: Mix.Dep.Loader.to_dep/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1043: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
%
```

erlang and elixir has been installed via [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl) and [asdf](https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf).
and my installation log is here http://otiai10.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/03/154953

envirionment

- MacOS: 10.11.2
- Erlang: 18.0
- Elixir: 1.1.1

What is happening and what should I do?

Comment: can you install hex manually by running "mix local.hex" ?

Comment: thanks for comment! Running `mix local.hex` gives the same error output :(
Does it seems like an error while installing Hex, right?

Comment: Seems like it. Maybe you installed Erlang without SSL. Then you should explicitly install "erlang-ssl" packege. Also "asdf" manual says that you should "OS X: Install these via homebrew automake autoconf openssl libyaml readline libxslt libtool unixodbc". Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank! I tried building Erlang with `--enable-dynamic-ssl-lib` option, but it resulted in the same. Then I want to try `--with-ssl`, but do you have any idea where to specify openssl lib PATH on MacOS?

Comment: --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @biletskyy answered, it was missing of SSL on Erlang installed via kerl, unlike via brew.

If you want to build Erlang with ssl via kerl, you should pass `KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` like below

```
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl" kerl build 18.0 18.0-foo
```

Then install Elixir via asdf. The mix command would work well.

Thanks to [@biletskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321432/dmitry-biletskyy)

Comment: The asdf erlang plugin page lists this as pitfall when installing erlang on OSX: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang#dealing-with-openssl-issues-on-macos

Answer (score 26):

In case you arent using `kerl` and you already did `brew install openssl`, they added [`ERLANG_OPENSSL_PATH`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/195#issuecomment-301354356) option to asdf so you can do

```
asdf plugin-update erlang
ERLANG_OPENSSL_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl" asdf install erlang 21.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using asdf and had this same problem.  I typically used brew, but for erlang, I was using evm so I could have multiple versions.

This seemed to help me:
https://github.com/robisonsantos/evm/issues/28

I was using EVM and needed to point it to openssl in order to get `mix deps.get` to work.  In my case, I was on OTP 21.2, so I did this:

```
evm uninstall OTP_21.2
evm install OTP_21.2 --with-ssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

All was right with the world after that.  I could run `mix deps.get` once I did this.